# .net fire query to check valid query and retrieve column names

Tags: .net, ado.net

I'm writing a testing framework in .Net to test a list of queries. I want to accomplish these two goals

1. Check if the query is valid
2. Retrieve the columns names only.

I dont care about the data part. In some cases, there could be time consuming queries. I just want it to return ASAP. Whats the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used a data reader & wrapped a try-catch around it. When the query succeeds I am able to read the column names. When it fails, it will return the error that SQL server reports.